# Python Portable + Geany Portable - "program exited with code 0"

Tags: python, geany

I just changed my work PC and wanted to continue my work with Python but I have a problem that won't go away.

I have `Geany 1.3.1` portable and `Python Portable 3.2.5.1` and can't for the life of me print something in terminal. A simple job as printing `print ("Hello world")` and building it with F5 just displays,

> (program exited with code: 0) Press any key to continue...

My portable python destination path is `D:\Pictures\pth\PortablePython`

I tried different combinations of paths for Compile and execute but to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your code + how you are launching it?

Comment: What is _python portable_?

Comment: This is normal behavior. F5 is running your program, not building it. There is no 1.3.1, it's 1.31. Please check manual for details on how to configure the run-script-window. https://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's wondering about the actually usage of the tool and not connected to a coding question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below at the top of your script

```
#!"D:\Pictures\pth\PortablePython\python.exe"
```

You could also use **Build → Set build commands** to set the executable

Comment: Hi, Saurabh.

I tried your first suggestion adding #! at the top of my script.

I received 

`Python 3.2.5 (default May 15 2013, 23:06:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.
Portable Python >>>`

My execute path is `"D:\Pictures\pth\PortablePython\Python-Portable.exe"`

My compile path is `"D:\Pictures\pth\PortablePython\Python-Portable.exe"`

How can i crack this nut?

Comment: At the top add: ```#!"D:\Pictures\pth\PortablePython\Python-Portable.exe"```

Comment: Thanks, Saurabh. Unfortunately this did not work. I'm gonna give this up and work only fron home.